# Error when copying from sheet of one workbook to another

Tags: vba, copy

I'm copying a sheet from one workbook (that is closed) to one with the code.

When I try to run the macro it gives me a Syntax error on the **set wbsecond** line (line 21 and 22)

Any idea how I can fix this?

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
Dim wbfirst As Workbook
Dim wbsecond As Workbook

Dim staticFolder As String
Dim dateFormat As String

'location of the parent folder
staticFolder = "C:\Users\WibblyWobblyy\Downloads\Test"

'provided previous month YYYYMM

dateFormat = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Date), "yyyymm", 1)

'workbook with the code
Set wbfirst = ThisWorkbook

'workbook that needs to be copied over from
Set wbsecond = Application.Workbooks.Open(staticFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "NTMR" & " - " & dateFormat & ".xlsx",
        UpdateLinks:=0)


    wbsecond.Activate

    Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Select
    Range("A1:AD1105").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Stop
```

Comment: You are missing a line continuation character (` _`) at the end of the first line of the two-line statement.

Comment: `wbsecond.Activate` , `Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Select` , `Range("A1:AD1105").Select` and `Selection.Copy` should be `wbsecond.Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Range("A1:AD1105").Copy` - shorter, and without using so many `Select`

Comment: @YowE3K        'workbook that needs to be copied over from
    Set wbsecond = Application.Workbooks.Open(staticFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "NTMR" & " - " & dateFormat & ".xlsx", _UpdateLinks:=0)    gives me an error too

Comment: @wasimakram101 - Are you still getting a syntax error?  Or are you now getting an error because the file doesn't exist, etc?

Comment: @YowE3k still giving me a syntax error

Comment: You didn't add the line continuation character, and then merge the two lines into one did you?

Comment: @ShaiRado got it, any recommendation for pasting?   im getting an error on `Destination:= wbfirst.Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Range("A1")'   the error being Expected: Expression

Comment: @YowE3k yep that was the problem. Thank you :) any idea on how I can fix an expected:expression error on ' Destination:= wbfirst.Sheets("NTMR EC investments list").Range("A1") '

Comment: I don't see any line like that in your code.  It appears to be the end of a `Copy` command, but the only "copy" in your code is `Selection.Copy` and it doesn't include a destination parameter.  (I suggest you create a new question if you have a new problem with different code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An executable statement in VBA can be terminated in two ways:

- Using an *instruction separator* token (`:`) to separate same-line instructions;
- Using an *end of line* token (`[NEWLINE]`).

This means a *logical code line* ends when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

A *logical code line* can span multiple *physical code lines*, using a *line continuation* token (`_`):

```
Set wbsecond = Application.Workbooks.Open( _
    staticFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "NTMR" & " - " & dateFormat & ".xlsx", _
    UpdateLinks:=0)
```

That's `[WS][UNDERSCORE]` - the whitespace is required.

So, what happened here:

```
Set wbsecond = Application.Workbooks.Open(staticFolder & "\" & dateFormat & "\" & "Source files" & "\" & "NTMR" & " - " & dateFormat & ".xlsx",
```

Is that this was parsed as a whole logical line, because it's terminated with a `[NEWLINE]`. But the right-hand side of the assignment can't be parsed as a valid expression, because the `.Open` member call isn't completed - it ends with a comma, whereas per VBA grammar it should end with a closing parenthesis.

This is what gives you the syntax error you're getting.

When you mean to have an instruction span more than one *physical line of code*, you need to terminate each "partial logical code line" with a *line continuation* `[WS][UNDERSCORE]`.

Comment: Understood. Works perfectly now.